# Wordpress get Ajax response for total post per page

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, custom-post-type, form-data

**Aim**

The **total** to be equal to the amount of post within the selected category or sub category.

**What im getting**

I am getting 0 when trying to get the number of post available in a category.

I have tried (*code bellow*), however I keep getting the response 0 for **total**

**Summarey**

So I have a custom post type **custom_post** and I am trying to get the number of post in a selected the category / subcategory selected (*using standard category and sub category type taxonomy*)

I am using the **category / sub-category ID**.

**My ajax**

```
<?php // the ajax function
add_action('wp_ajax_filterPosts', 'filterPosts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filterPosts', 'filterPosts');

function filterPosts()
{
    $response = [
        'posts' => "",
    ];
    
    $all_args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // returns all posts
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );
    
    $filter_args = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );
    
     if ($_POST['limit']) {
        $filter_args['posts_per_page'] = max (0, (int) $_POST['limit']);
    }
    
    if (isset($_POST['offset'])) {                      
        $filter_args['offset'] = max (0, (int)$_POST['offset']);
    }

     if ($_POST['post_type_js']) {
        $filter_args['post_type'] = $_POST['post_type_js'];
    }

    if ($_POST['category']) {
        $filter_args['cat'] = $_POST['category'];
        
        // Get the total number of posts for the category
        $all_args['total'] = $_POST['total'];

    }

    $filter_query = new WP_Query($filter_args);

    $all_query = new WP_Query($all_args);

    

    if ($filter_query->have_posts()) :
        while ($filter_query->have_posts()) : $filter_query->the_post();
            $response['posts'] .= load_template_part('/template-parts/posts-filter/single-post');
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;

    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
}
```

**My javascript**

```
Alpine.data("filterPosts", (adminURL) => ({
    posts: "",
    limit: 6,
    total: null,
    category: null,
    post_type_js: post_id,
    showDefault: true,
    showFiltered: false,
    offset: 0,
    
        filterPosts(id) {
        this.showDefault = false;
        this.showFiltered = true;
        this.category = id;
        this.offset = 0; // <-- reset offset to zero
        this.total = 0;
        this.fetchPosts();
    },
    
    loadMore() {
        this.loadingMore = true;
        this.total = null;
        this.offset += 6;
        this.showFiltered = true;
        this.fetchPosts(true);
    },

    fetchPosts(append = false) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("action", "filterPosts");
        formData.append("limit", this.limit);
        formData.append("post_type_js", this.post_type_js);
        formData.append("offset", this.offset); 

        if (this.category) {
            formData.append("category", this.category);
            formData.append("total", this.total);
        }

    fetch(adminURL, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
            if (append) {
                // Appends posts to the end of existing posts data
                this.posts = this.posts.concat(res.posts);
            } else {
                // Resets the posts data with new data
                this.posts = res.posts;
            }

            this.loading = false;
        });
    },
    
    getTotal() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("action", "filterPosts");

    fetch(adminURL, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
        this.total = res.total;
    });
},

init() {
    this.getTotal(
```

**Response in console**

```
action: filterPosts
limit: 6
post_type_js: custom_post
offset: 6
category: 1094
total: 0
```

Comment: does it return 0 posts only when you filter by category? if so, are you passing the category ID or the slug?

Comment: always 0, and getting category by ID

Comment: the category you're querying, is the built-in taxonomy "Category" (the one used by standard posts) or is it custom?

Comment: standard one built in

Comment: `post_type_js: custom_post` so you're querying standard posts, is it a custom post type somehow related to the build-in taxonomy "category"?

Comment: the custom_post is the post type im calling using standard category and sub category taxonomy

Comment: Apologies I may of miss understood your question

Comment: I have updated the question to include a better description

Comment: `$all_query = new WP_Query($all_args);` - you are not using that variable `$all_query` anywhere else any more in the code you have shown us - so how is this result or its count of records, supposed to make its way back to the client side then?

Comment: you have a good point, but even if i set to my original '$filter_args' it still wont pass the data